# How to split changes in multiple linked working trees?

Tags: git, git-stash, separation-of-concerns, git-worktree

On my local repo I have the *main working tree* full of **many unrelated changes**.

I want to **split my messy index into many distinct tidy linked worktrees**, so I can isolate changes by concern and handle them without getting insane or rely on memory.

*What's the minimal amount of steps to redistribute chunks among different worktrees?*

---

#### Example

```
$ git status
 M .env
 M .gitignore
 M Dockerfile
 M README.md
?? untracked.file
?? worktree/
```

I would

- use `git stash save Concern001 -p`, to interactively select the changes I want to put into Concern001
- to then `git stash apply Concern001` into my worktree

  - (created via `git worktree add worktree/Concern001`).\

But this approach fails in the case I want to move **untracked changes** to another worktree. Trying `git stash save Concern001 -p -u`

> Can't use --patch and --include-untracked or --all at the same time

Moreover, the presence of the `worktree/` directory among the untracked files makes the stashing error prone; although I can fix this adding `/worktree` to `.gitignore`.

For now I tried:

- `git add -p` to select the changes to isolate
- `git commit -m 'Concern001'` => commit-SHA
- `cd worktree/Concern001`
- `git cherry-pick <commit-SHA>`
- `git reset HEAD^` to get again the changes in the worktree index
- `cd ../..` (back to main worktree)
- `git reset HEAD^`..... but this will restore the changes I just moved away; and if I instead use `git reset HEAD^ --hard` then I would loose all the other temporary changes from the index.

This approach look verbose, cumbersome and error prone.

---

#### Is there a sequence of `git` commands to select specific changes and move them between worktrees, without having to do too many intermediate operations❓

Ideally I'd use `git stash` but doesn't cover all the use cases.

Comment: I personally hate, er, dislike, er, hate, er ... something between those two, the `git stash` command. I'm not obsessed with minimality, so I'd just do some `git worktree add`s and then start working in each working tree, using `git diff` on the main worktree to see what I need to bring over, and my editor to bring things over.

Comment: You mean using the editor for *copy-pasting* among worktrees? It would feel error prone to me. – I have too many different unrelated changes (already) in the main worktree; I'm looking for a way to re-distribute the changes in separate worktrees, so I can fix the initial mess, exactly because I am afraid to make mistakes working it out manually.

Comment: Once you have changes X and Y separated, `git diff` in worktree X will show change X, and `git diff` in worktree Y will show change Y, and `git diff` in the main worktree will show them mixed together. Seems relatively straightforward, at that point, to subtract out X and Y from the mixed-together parts, leaving you with changes Z1+Z2+...+Zn, etc. If you missed something, eventually you find that the main worktree still has something in it that needs to go to worktree X, Y, or Zi.